# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment, truffle-console, truffle-develop

### Gettting Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction

```
function getLatestPrice() public payable returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
          arr.push(price);// every method call current price will be pushed into an array
      emit PriceFeed(msg.sender,price);
        return price;
    }

Calling the method from the truffle console
Assign.deployed().then(instance => assign = instance)   web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc }) 
tried:
-->assign.getLatestPrice(accounts[1], { from: accounts[1], value: 10000000000000000000 })
```

-->instance.getLatestPrice({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 3000000, value: 100}, function(err,res){});
-->instance.getLatestPrice({from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});

Comment: Also see [vmexceptionwhileprocessingtransactionrevert.com](https://vmexceptionwhileprocessingtransactionrevert.com)

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg yeah tried but doesn't work for me. When i see instance method, the signature is defined as--getLatestPrice: [Function] {
    call: [Function],
    sendTransaction: [Function],
    estimateGas: [Function],
    request: [Function]
  }                                                     Do you have any idea, how do i call this ?

Comment: Switch to Hardhat and use [console.log](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network.html#solidity-console-log) to investigate your issue. Here's a ready-to-use [template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) for you (disclaimer: I authored the template).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I will try. Thanks for the quick response